# How can you add an array to a GSList without a variable?

Tags: c, arrays, glib, singly-linked-list

I'm working with something like this, however it's throwing errors.

I would just put the array in a variable and pass it that way but I'm looking at almost 500 lines such as this of unpatterned data. (So I can't use a loop)

Besides, the whole point of using a GSList was to avoid the restrictions of jagged arrays

```
list43333 = g_slist_append(list43333,{11,12,13,14,15,17,18,20,22,25,30});
```

**Edit:** casting with `(int[]) gives:

```
csgtk.h:14: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
csgtk.h:14: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘list43333’
csgtk.h:14: error: conflicting types for ‘list43333’
csgtk.h:12: note: previous definition of ‘list43333’ was here
csgtk.h:14: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘g_slist_append’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gslist.h:52: note: expected ‘struct GSList *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
csgtk.h:14: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
csgtk.h:14: error: initializer element is not constant
```

Edit: Literal copy paste to show it's not out of scope (Note, this is in the top level of a .h file):

```
GSList * list43333 = NULL;
list43333 = g_slist_prepend(list43333,(int[]){});
```

main file

```
#include "csgtk.h"

GHashTable * widgetbuffer;
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler doesn't know what the type of your array is, so something like this should work.

```
list43333 = g_slist_append(list43333,(int[]){11,12,13,14,15});
```

however you should consider how you're doing this, it would be better to make a single static constant array and add that to your `GSList` since here you're going to be hitting an O(n²) kind of run time since it has to walk the list for every append.

Comment: But if I added a single array wouldn't that mean it would all end up in the same GSlist item?

Comment: I could use `g_slist_prepend()` then `g_slist_reverse()` afterwards to solve the performance problem, but I still can't run it.

Comment: in response to your first comment, yes, you're right, I wasn't thinking, and yes you should probably do the 'g_slist_prepend()` bit.

Comment: the new warnings look like you haven't declared `list43333` anywhere so it's defaulting to `int`...

Comment: But I have: `GSList * list43333 = NULL;` According to the references (And some code I have already working which does exactly that) this is the correct way to initialize a GSList... I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Just double check where you declare it, it seems to be out of scope where you're building up your list.

Comment: Well it's not out of scope but it is set in a header file to avoid clogging up my main file with 40kb worth of slist statements.

Comment: Never mind, I couldn't get this to work, I'll just use something else

Comment: @JV, it's been a while but I just tried it, and it worked.  Would you mind to clarify your question for others? It is a good question for compound literal.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried the same thing, and it works.  gcc 4.7.1 on Debian unstable amd64.  BTW, `(int []){1, 2, 3}` is ISO C99 Compound Literals.

```
#include <glib.h>

int main()
{
        GSList *l;

        l = g_slist_alloc();
        l = g_slist_append(l, (int []){1, 2, 3});

        return 0;
}
```

`$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -g $(pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0) main.c`